# Cascading delete removes unintended records

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship, cascade

I typically develop in MS Access and occasionally connect to a MySQL back end. I have a MySQL back end that isn't cascading deletes as I'd expect when I delete records. I'm wondering if it's because of how I've set up the table relationships (foreign keys). I don't know enough about MySQL to know if I've done this right. In designer view I set up the relationships using the designer view in MySQL. For a composite primary key field (InterviewID, Coder ID) in tblInterviews I created two separate relations to tblSB for each of these two primary key fields (tblSB includes a 3rd field, SBid, as its composite PK). The designer view is a little different from Access in that you can't highlight more than one field at a time to set up relationships. I did find forums that discuss the syntax for setting up the relationship with the foreign key but I don't know if it's equivalent to what I did in designer. I suspect not because currently when I try to delete a specific record (unique InterviewID, CoderID combination) *ALL* interview records for the CoderID in the InterviewID, CoderID combination get deleted (and this cascades through to other child tables as well). I also am wondering if I need to set up my primary key in a way that I am not currently doing (e.g., setting it up as an index, also). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably defined 2 FK constraints (one on each column, referencing separately each one of the 2 columns of the PK), instead of one FK (on the composite 2-column referencing the composite PK).

Comment: Or you defined the FK, in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see what you've created, look at the DDL. (SHOW CREATE TABLE)

To enforce foreign key constraints--including cascading deletes--you probably want to use the innodb engine. The myisam engine will accept DDL that declares foreign keys, but it won't enforce them.

MySQL will let a foreign key target a non-unique column. [The MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) say

> Deviation from SQL standards: A FOREIGN KEY constraint that references
>   a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL. It is an InnoDB extension to
>   standard SQL.

They call it an extension to SQL. I call it a mistake.

It means you can declare tblSB.interviewID as a foreign key referencing tblInterviews.interviewID. A standard SQL dbms wouldn't allow that.

The [5.6 docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) say

> However, the system does not enforce a requirement that the referenced
>   columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT NULL. The handling of foreign key
>   references to nonunique keys or keys that contain NULL values is not
>   well defined for operations such as UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are
>   advised to use foreign keys that reference only UNIQUE and NOT NULL
>   keys.

To my way of thinking, they're saying, "It was a bad idea, but we don't know how to fix it. So it's up to you to avoid it.  We could warn you when you try it, but we're not going to do that, either."

---

Based on your comments, I'd say this constraint is right . . .

```
CONSTRAINT tblInterviewRecordtblSB 
FOREIGN KEY (InterviewID, CoderID) 
  REFERENCES tblinterviewrecord (InterviewID, CoderID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

but these two are not, and should be deleted.

```
CONSTRAINT tblSB_ibfk_1 
FOREIGN KEY (InterviewID) 
  REFERENCES tblinterviewrecord (InterviewID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
CONSTRAINT tblSB_ibfk_2 
FOREIGN KEY (CoderID) 
  REFERENCES tblinterviewrecord (CoderID) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Ok, all tables are definitely InnoDB. I'm pretty sure that I defined the FK in the correct direction but it sounds like separate relationships on the two fields of the fk is not the same as a relationship on the composite.  I'll have to check the DDL in the morning--no access at the moment.

Comment: That's right, two relationships on the two columns is not the same as one relationship on the pair.

Comment: I checked SHOW CREATE TABLE to see what I have and here are the results. It's really not clear to me whether this is correct for what I need:

Comment: tblSB---For parent table tblInterviewRecord---... PRIMARY KEY (`InterviewID`,`CoderID`),
 KEY `CoderID` (`CoderID`),
 KEY `InterviewID` (`InterviewID`),
 KEY `tblIntervieweeTypestblInterviewRecord` (`IntervieweeTypeID`),
 CONSTRAINT `tblinterviewrecord_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CoderID`) REFERENCES `tblcoders` (`CoderID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: For child table tblSB---... UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`InterviewID`,`CoderID`,`SB_ID`),
 KEY `CoderID` (`CoderID`),
 KEY `InterviewID` (`InterviewID`),
 KEY `SB_ID` (`SB_ID`),
 CONSTRAINT `tblInterviewRecordtblSB` FOREIGN KEY (`InterviewID`, `CoderID`) REFERENCES `tblinterviewrecord` (`InterviewID`, `CoderID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `tblSB_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`InterviewID`) REFERENCES `tblinterviewrecord` (`InterviewID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

Comment: CONSTRAINT `tblSB_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CoderID`) REFERENCES `tblinterviewrecord` (`CoderID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Actually, I am just going to get rid of all of my existing table relationships and will start over by using the ALTER TABLE syntax to establish the FK relationships.

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting the picture. The designer appears to show only simple key relationships. When I set up the constraints using the syntax and then run SHOW CREATE TABLE I'm able to see the constraints. I DO NOT see the constraints in the table/structure/relation view. That seems odd to me because I'm not able to see the relation in designer or the constraint in relation view. If you hadn't suggested SHOW CREATE then I'd be trying to explain to my boss why there's a fist imprint in my monitor.

Comment: I need to do more work before I am really able to tell if this is the solution or if my problem is actually multi-part.

Comment: Catcall, thanks for your help. I was able to properly set up the constraints and check that they were established. Interestingly, the relationship would show in the Designer view aftwerward but *only* if the key was a simple key. Composite key relationships were only demonstrated by using SHOW TABLE.

Comment: The Designer does not show the relation lines between a composite PK and a composite FK. Unfortunately for me, after I set up and confirmed all of the FK constraints, Access would still not play nice with MySQL. My form recordsources were not obeying the table constraints. I chalked this up to the complex nature of my front end db (multiple nested subforms among other things).

Comment: Part of my daily work involves using an Access front end to a PostgreSQL back end. I don't have any trouble with it, but I don't have subforms nested in subforms. (I decided long ago that I just don't like more than one nested subform. I pop open detailed forms instead.)

Comment: Duly noted and now sufficiently experienced. I'll definitely keep this in mind now.